# How to use Fabric.js to define templates - special consideration on text objects

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

Having a look at Fabric.js, I am considering the replacement of my current development, based on pure javascript/HTML and use Fabric.js.
My current development helps users define "layout templates" and one of my main concerns is the ability to define a fixed size "text" area with fixed text properties (font-name, font-size, text-decoration...) that will accept text when populating the template.

From all my readings, I haven't found any solution yet that would prevent such "fixed size text area with fixed text properties" from shrinking and adapting either its boundaries to the text content or even worse to change the text font-size to fit the boundaries.

In other words, I need to be able to define a "text area" (to define all properties such as external dimension of the box, border, background... but also font-name, font-size and all types of font properties) so that when I put some text in it, it simply accepts the text with the properties I defined earlier.

Anyone with some hints on this topic?

Many thanks